# Math expression not working on Stack Exchange homepage: pi

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange-2.0

Just a minor bug: I noticed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/is-there-an-integral-that-proves-pi-333-106) on math.stackexchange, which has pi in its name. (Cool feature, by the way). However, when it was displayed on http://stackexchange.com, it shows it with the slash and question mark.

I don't know if anyone cares; such a minor thing as it is, but I felt compelled to report it anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is by design -- math uses [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathjax) , and we don't support that on stackexchange.com.