# Remove mathjax question titles from the ads, or actually render the equations

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, advertising, rendering

This SE-promoting ad, that [managed to cause some problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57507/page-links-not-always-showing-at-the-bottom-of-stackoverflow-com/57518#57518) in the past. (Now redesigned a bit).

Sometimes it displays a question title from math.stackexchange that includes a [mathjax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60282/math-expression-not-working-on-stackexchange-homepage-pi/60283#60283) expression. In this case, the expression is shown as mere text. Confused me a bit when I saw it first time.

Would be better to either render the actual equation for that ad (would be much more appealing, wouldn't it?) or ban questions with mathjax in their titles from appearing.

Comment: I see your point; on the other hand, mathematicians (who the ad is obviously for) are ususally used to reading LaTeX.

Comment: They also look really funny in the automated tweets.